# Getting "Unexpected reserved word" when doing await in export module?

Tags: javascript, import, async-await, export

In my export module, I want to use await

```
export default {
    template : await (await fetch("template.html")).text();
}
```

but this doesn't work. It gets `Unexpected reserved word` because of `await`.

Note: this is pure client side, no babel or webpack or node.js.

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure top-level `await` is available in your environment?

Comment: await works in chrome, I can use it in my other js files, I think it has something to do with the export....?

Comment: L'exportation du module doit se faire de manière synchrone!

Comment: This is still a stage-3 proposal

Comment: where is the link for that?

Comment: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await ... will work soon in up to date browsers.

Comment: try adding async for await operations.